# Variables and Assignment statements

Tags: java, variables

Im having a hard time finishing the problem. I don't know what to do with the int and double values for the calculations. How would i go through with solving them. I am using Jgrasp for my class. 
Calculations:

Standard: (20.0 + 40.0 + 5.0 + 60.0 + 30.0 ) / 5

Weighted: 20.0 * 0.15 + 40.0 * 0.1 + 4.0 * 0.2 + 60.0 * 0.25 + 30.0 * 0.3

standard carpet cost: $620.0

weighted carpet cost: $640.0

The Code that I have is

```
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

  public class Project2A

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    int sqftbrm = 20;
    int sqftdrm = 40;
    int sqfthal = 5;
    int sqftgrm = 60;
    int sqftstr = 30;

   double bf = .15;
   double df = .10;
   double hf = .20;
   double gf = 0.25;
   double sf = .30;

char stndCst[] = {"(sqftbrm + sqftdrm +sqfthal + sqftgrm + sqftstr)"/5};
String stdcst = new String(stndCst);
System.out.print(stdcst);

char wtAvg[] = {"sqftbrm*bf" + "sqftdrm*df" + "sqfthal*hf" + "sqftgrm*gf" + "sqftstr*sf");
String wtAverage = new String(wtAvg);
System.out.print(wtAverage);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please limit your posts to just the current problem you are having rather than the whole assignment description? Please [edit] to do that.

Comment: i edited the post, so it has my question, and some background information, and my code @cricket_007

Comment: You have `;` after your `main` method prototype. You are putting your code in an initialization block...

Comment: thanks @Jezor, but I still don't know how to set up the calculations portion of my code. I don't know what to use, and how to apply it.

Comment: @JasvantSinghDosanjh what exactly do you have trouble with? Which line? I see no calculations in your code, have you even made an attempt to write it yourself?

Comment: @Jezor, Yes, but I don't know how to fix it. I am coding for the first time, so this is all new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside of the fact that you should probably be using an IDE to easily identify your mistakes.... Semi colon on `main` method, missing brackets, invalid variable types, etc.

All you have is two arrays with one string value each.

```
char stndCst[] = {"(sqftbrm + sqftdrm +sqfthal + sqftgrm + sqftstr)"/5};

char wtAvg[] = {"sqftbrm*bf" + "sqftdrm*df" + "sqfthal*hf" + "sqftgrm*gf" + "sqftstr*sf"} ;
```

If you want to do math with some variables, then remove the quotes.

For example,

```
double stndCst = (sqftbrm + sqftdrm +sqfthal + sqftgrm + sqftstr) / 5.0;

double wtAvg = sqftbrm*bf + sqftdrm*df + sqfthal*hf + sqftgrm*gf + sqftstr*sf ;
```

Comment: Once if have done what you have told me to do@cricket_007, i am still getting an error with my char wtAvg[] = {sqftbrmbf + sqftdrmdf + sqfthalhf + sqftgrmgf + sqftstr*sf} ;

Comment: I'm not able to guess at all the problems that could arise with the code you have. You have to be more specific than "an error"

Comment: Why are you using a `char[]` to store a single integer? Who has taught you that?

Comment: Project2A.java:19: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char     I am confused as to what I should change it to. @cricket_007

Comment: What does `char` mean to you? That isn't the correct variable type. I'm trying to help you learn and think about the problem

Comment: char means character. should i change char to int num1 and num2, something along those lines? but, then how would convert int to string?

Comment: You are using double values in your calculations, so `int`  won't work either. I've updated my answer, regardless

Comment: i am know getting an error, saying "Project2A.java:23: error: no suitable constructor found for String(double)". How do i fix this? @cricket_007

Comment: Just print the double variable. Again, I don't understand where you are learning that you need to explicitly create String objects

Comment: actually i added Double.toString and it works!, but I am not getting the answers that my professor wants me to get.

Comment: You don't need toString. Just `System.out.println(stndCst)`

Comment: I got it to work! thanks soon much. I really appreciate your patience, persistence, thank so much, again!

Comment: Welcome. Don't take the downvotes too personally, just make sure to read over the help center about asking questions at some point. http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking